# How can i create the sqlite database each time

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

**I am working on the app which send the location to sqlite database when there is no data connection available. As soon connection available the whole data of sqlite database is send to the server.so i want each time when data send to the server a new sqlite database is created.**

Comment: Why not simply delete what you have sent successfully. There is no need to recreate your entire db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the contents of a SqlLite table:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
db.delete("YourTable", null, null);
db.close();
```

OR, you can delete the entire database file:

```
context.deleteDatabase("YourDatabase.db");
```